# How to insert a range of values inside a slice of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': np.repeat(pd.date_range('2019-08-01', '2019-08-03'), 3),
              'group': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
              'id_appear': [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

That looks like:

```
df.sort_values('group', inplace=True)


    timestamp   group   id_appear
0   2019-08-01  A       NaN
1   2019-08-01  B       NaN
3   2019-08-02  B       NaN
4   2019-08-02  B       NaN
6   2019-08-03  B       NaN
2   2019-08-01  C       NaN
5   2019-08-02  C       NaN
7   2019-08-03  C       NaN
8   2019-08-03  C       NaN
```

But with nearly 6 million rows.

I want to insert a series of numbers between 1 and N, where N represents the number of times that a group appears per day.

I'm expecting the following:

```
timestamp       group   id_appear
0   2019-08-01  A       1.0
1   2019-08-01  B       1.0
3   2019-08-02  B       1.0
4   2019-08-02  B       2.0
6   2019-08-03  B       1.0
2   2019-08-01  C       1.0
5   2019-08-02  C       1.0
7   2019-08-03  C       1.0
8   2019-08-03  C       2.0
```

I tried the following code:

```py
indexes = df.index
count = 1
saved = None
for pos, (index, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):

    if pos == 0 or ((row['group'] != saved['group']) or (row['timestamp'] != saved['timestamp'])):
        count = 1
    else:
        count +=1
    df.loc[index, 'id_appear'] = count

    saved = row
```

And, although it works, it is extremely inefficient. How could I improve the efficience of this code?

Thank you!

Comment: `df.groupby(['timestamp', 'group']).cumcount().add(1)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace all NaN in `id_appear` with some number (I used 0)
2. Run group_by, count on columns `group` and `timestamp` to a new data frame
3. Merge the old data frame and new one

Code as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': np.repeat(pd.date_range('2019-08-01', '2019-08-03'), 3),
                   'group': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                   'id_appear': [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan]})
df['id_appear'] = 0
df_ = df.groupby(by=['group','timestamp']).count()
df.drop(['id_appear'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = pd.merge(left=df, right=df_, how='inner', on=['timestamp','group'])
```

Gives an output

```
   timestamp group  id_appear
0 2019-08-01     A          1
1 2019-08-01     B          1
2 2019-08-01     C          1
3 2019-08-02     B          2
4 2019-08-02     B          2
5 2019-08-02     C          1
6 2019-08-03     B          1
7 2019-08-03     C          2
8 2019-08-03     C          2
```